# File or folder exist, but throws 404 in IIS web server

Tags: php, iis-8, fat-free-framework

I built a web application with F3 framework. On my local (XAMPP), everything went well. But, after I uploaded it to the server (IIS Web Server), the message 404 - "file or folder doen't exist" appeared. I am confused, what causes this problem can occur.

Note :

- I create new site in IIS with the root folder pointing to "D:/www/my-project".
- Default root folder is "C:/inetpub/wwwroot".
- There are a domain that points to the ip server.
- When I access the domain, the first page appears. But after switching page / route, the next page throws 404.

Comment: Have you configured the web.config file?

Comment: @ParthPatel, I only change the default document point to file in my application. Sorry I'm new to web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create web.config file at the root and put the code as below
(this config might differ based on your app structure)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Application" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The code structure is like .htaccess, does that mean I don't need to use .htaccess?

Comment: @Zhumpex .htaccess is for apache server and web.config is for IIS server

Comment: Thank you for your help and new knowledge about web.config. The application is running normally.